# Combine ansible-vault with prompted variables?

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

The problem I have right now is that, to use ansible-vault encrypted strings, I need to specify on the command line `--vault-id=foo@prompt` .

I don't use encrypted strings very often, so I'd rather have my play notice that I'm going to use an encrypted string, and prompt for the password only when absolutely necessary.

Is this possible?  Something along the lines of

```
  vars:
    string1: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;foo
          66306438623164653061623661376331643537303931663562326336386234333935373661623261
          3930633662616462316133633236383530356561346233640a386439316638313361333437386435
          38346635626533313266663436666163386238616266623038666364323232393465656665643831
          6437616339616463360a383263333965366264633562343965386137313364613737356666623562
          3033
  vars_prompt:
  - name: "cryptpasswd"
    prompt: "ansible-vault password"
    private: yes
  tasks:
  - name: "secret string"
    debug:
      msg: "secret message is {{ string1 }}"
```

... and then my password is somehow available to decrypt the string when needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a totally random password string and add it to a password file.

in your ansible.cfg file:

```
vault_password_file = vault_pass.txt
```

add the file vault_pass.txt to your ansible working directory with your password and that's it.

If your using git make sure to add the password file to your .gitignore file.

Comment: Thank you.  Your comment about ansible.cfg led me to realize that an individual directory (although sadly, not an individual play or playbook) can have its own ansible.cfg .  That and your suggesting should solve my problem.