# overriding options in the ansible config

Tags: ansible, ansible-vault

In [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1286187/combine-ansible-vault-with-prompted-variables), I discovered that I can put options into a local `ansible.cfg` file.  But can I override them?

I have an `ansible.cfg` file that contains

```
[defaults]
vault_password_file = /home/hymie/ansible/foo
```

And I can use this file automatically:

```
$ echo "hi there" |  ansible-vault encrypt_string
Reading plaintext input from stdin. (ctrl-d to end input)
!vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          64386133613865366565336365333166623538613239636464303931646330323061376239363639
          3136376163613132613130306630626365643133366664310a353030303434346336396233616363
          62323464313737663135303636646264373737393930326132386231363561653865646436313439
          3231353132643364340a316431626332626633646135613064353133633038356434323537326633
          3035
Encryption successful
```

But now, I am unable to use/select a different password:

```
$ echo "hi there" |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --ask-vault-pass
New Vault password:
Confirm New Vault password:
ERROR! Only one --vault-id can be used for encryption. This includes passwords from configuration and cli.

$ echo "hi there" |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-password-file=/tmp/foo
ERROR! Only one --vault-id can be used for encryption. This includes passwords from configuration and cli.

$ echo "hi there" |  ansible-vault encrypt_string --vault-id=@prompt
New vault password (default):
Confirm vew vault password (default):
ERROR! Only one --vault-id can be used for encryption. This includes passwords from configuration and cli.
```

This seems like the Wrong Behavior.

Why isn't my command-line option (either to prompt for a password or to select a different password file) overriding the configuration-file option to use a specific predefined password file?  Am I doing something wrong?  Or is ansible just like this, no overriding configuration file variables?

Comment: The error seems clear to me.  You can only assign a single valid-id to be used for encryption.  Where else have you assigned the vault-id?

Comment: The error clearly indicates this was intentional. You are requesting a new feature / change, you should do it on GitHub, not SuperUser.

Comment: @techraf So is this a standard ansible thing, that once a setting is defined in ansible.cfg , it cannot be overridden by a command-line option?

Comment: That error is thrown because `/tmp/foo` is not an executable bash script that should `echo ${VAULT_PASS}`

Comment: @MincăDanielAndrei You are mistaken.  https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/vault.html#providing-vault-passwords  clearly says "To specify a vault password in a text file, use the --vault-password-file option", as does the help text from ansible-vault --help .

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue yesterday with the same error thrown and your configuration.

Apparently that error was thrown because my `ansible.cfg` from CWD was poiting to a `vault_password_file` and I was also passing the `--vault-password-file` in the CLI as argument, so referencing the Vault Password File twice throws that error: `ERROR! Only one --vault-id can be used for encryption. This includes passwords from configuration and cli.`

Which is exactly what the error says, the fact that you're passing that param twice, but in a different way.

So, a way to fix this is either remove the `vault_password_file=` reference from `ansible.cfg` and only pass it through the cli `--vault-password-file`, or just leave it in the `ansible.cfg` thus avoiding to type `--vault-password-file` in the cli again, it's up to you.